# Dependent dropdown lists with selenium in Python3

Tags: drop-down-menu, webdriver, dropdown

I am writing a python script that should automatically download an excel file from a website. Yet, in order to generate the excel file, several drop-down lists need to be selected (eg.: Select continent, then select country, then select city... etc.). This means that I need to select one value from the drop-down menu "A" in order for the drop-down menu "B" to show the available values, once the I have selected a value in the drop-down menu "B" I can continue with drop-down "C", and so on.

The problem is that every time I select one value from one drop-down menu (say, from drop-down menu "A") the website is refreshed in order to show the values available for the subsequent drop-down menu.

So far I have been able to access the website with selenium while selecting only a value from the first drop-down menu (eg. Continent), however I am facing difficulties in dealing with the subsequent drop-down menus. Does anyone have an idea of how I could deal with this?

So far my code looks like:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://daten.ktbl.de/feldarbeit/entry.html#0")

element1=driver.find_element_by_name("hgId")

drp1=Select(element1)

drp1.select_by_visible_text("Bodenbearbeitung")
```

Many thanks in advance,

best
Chico

Answer (score 0):

Well, found out:
wait for the ajax to load the website after the selection:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```